# Find a date from a specific list of date

Tags: c#, date

I am a beginner in c # and I can not find the solution for my problem.

I am creating a personal project that allows me to send reminders, I have a date list and I need to do tasks between two specific dates in real life.

I found how to get the next date from today's date but I can't find how to get the previous one

Here is my sample code

```
void calc_x_date()  
    {
        List<string> x_dates = new List<string>();
        x_dates.Add("10/01/2017");
        x_dates.Add("14/02/2017");
        x_dates.Add("14/03/2017");
        x_dates.Add("11/04/2017");
        x_dates.Add("09/05/2017");
        x_dates.Add("13/06/2017");
        x_dates.Add("04/07/2017");
        x_dates.Add("08/08/2017");
        x_dates.Add("12/09/2017");
        x_dates.Add("10/10/2017");
        x_dates.Add("14/11/2017");
        x_dates.Add("12/12/2017");

        var allDates = x_dates.Select(DateTime.Parse).OrderBy(d => d).ToList();

        var todayDate = DateTime.Today;
        var nextDate = todayDate >= allDates.Last()
             ? allDates.Last()
             : todayDate <= allDates.First()
                 ? allDates.First()
                 : allDates.First(d => d >= todayDate);

       string NextDate = nextDate.ToString(); // the closest next date from today          
       //string PreviousDate =   // the closest previous date from today   
    }
```

Could someone explain me how to find my previous date  please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not related to your current question, but an observation. A lot of beginning programmers seem to use `string`s all over the place when it's not appropriate. `string` should be the *last* data type you should consider using in most places. Here, for instance, your list *ought* to be a `List<DateTime>`. Similarly, `NextDate` and `PreviousDate` ought to be `DateTime`. Every time you find yourself writing `ToString` or `Parse`, you're probably inappropriately round-tripping your data through another `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Linq approach

```
List<string> x_dates = new List<string>();
x_dates.Add("10/01/2017");
x_dates.Add("14/02/2017");
x_dates.Add("14/03/2017");
x_dates.Add("11/04/2017");
x_dates.Add("09/05/2017");
x_dates.Add("13/06/2017");
x_dates.Add("04/07/2017");
x_dates.Add("08/08/2017");
x_dates.Add("12/09/2017");
x_dates.Add("10/10/2017");
x_dates.Add("14/11/2017");
x_dates.Add("12/12/2017");


DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
IEnumerable<DateTime> dt_dates = x_dates.Select(DateTime.Parse);

DateTime prev = dt_dates.Where(x => x < today)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                        .First();

DateTime next = dt_dates.Where(x => x > today)
                        .OrderBy(x => x)
                        .First();
```

---

alternative solution

```
DateTime prev = dt_dates.Where(x => x < today).Max();
DateTime next = dt_dates.Where(x => x > today).Min();
```

Comment: Evaluating `DateTime.Today` multiple times is a really bad idea - it could change between predicate evaluations. Additionally, there's no need to perform the subtraction - just order by the dates themselves, ascending or descending... or use `Max`/`Min`. Note that this code won't cope with scenarios where today is either equal-to-or-before the earliest date, or equal-to-or-later-than the last date.

Comment: It still fails in those edge cases though... that's why I'd suggest getting the index, as it's then easy to check.

Comment: @JonSkeet OP didn't specify the expected behaviour of this "today"-case but comparing with `today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)` could also help

Comment: Eek, I wouldn't suggest doing that. (Why seconds, rather than ticks, for example?) Basically, the OP *should* be considering the six different cases in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx): that will find the index of the date. If the index is 0 or more, then the exact date was found. If it's negative, then taking `~index` will get you the index where the date *would* have been inserted.

Once you've got that information, it's easy to find the value at the previous index or the next index - but you should consider all the cases of:

- Today is before all dates
- Today is after all dates
- Today is a date between the first and last date in the list, but isn't in the list
- Today is equal to the first date
- Today is equal to the last date
- Today is equal to a date in the list which isn't the first or last date

As asides:

- I would strongly encourage you to get in the habit of following .NET naming conventions as early as possible
- I'd encourage you not to use strings to represent dates unless you really need to
- If you're doing a lot of date/time work, you may find my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library easier to use correctly than `DateTime`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :)  Learning from books or tutorial is not easy, as I don't have time to go back to School,.

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates in string format works. It is however incredibly difficult to do date comparisons. You have to first cast it to numbers, handle the exceptions, etc.

C# has a DateTime object. You can store dates in this and ignore the time. DateTime objects can be compared using the < and > operators.

If you create a class with a start date and an end date, store these objects in a list(of tasks), would that solve your problem? You can also add a text of the task in a string to said object.